# Divergence theorem: 2 different results

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Given the vector field  $\vec a(r, \theta, \phi) = \frac3r \vec e_r = \frac3r \begin{pmatrix} \cos(\phi) \sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\phi) \sin(\theta) \\ \cos(\theta)\end{pmatrix}$, I have to calculcate the flux through a sphere with radius R.

To do this, I want to apply divergence theorem: 
$ \int_V\nabla \cdot \vec a = \int_A \vec a \cdot d\vec f  $

Applying the right side of the equation above gives me $12\pi R$, but the left side gives me $0$.

$\nabla \cdot \vec a = \frac{3}{r^2}\cos(\phi)\sin(\theta) + \frac{6}{r^2}\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)$

Thus, if you calculate $\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi$ in the volume integral you receive $0$ since $\int_0^{2\pi} \sin(x) dx= \int_0^{2\pi} \cos(x) dx = 0 $

Where is my mistake?

Comment: Did you include the jacobian bcoz' we are using the polar coordinates ?

Comment: Yes I did: $r^2 \sin(\theta) $

Comment: Then you will have to integrate $sin^2(\theta)$ and  $sin(\theta)cos(\theta)$.

Comment: Correct, but that doesn't matter if I integrate $\int_0^{2\pi}d\phi $

Comment: Did you actually check the conditions of the Divergence Theorem? This theorem is valid for the vector field being of class $C^1$ in a neighborhood of $V$. Your vector field has a singularity at $O$: it is not of class $C^1$ on $V$, hence you can't apply it. When you say the left hand side of your equation is $0$, you're applying Fubini's Theorem (but it's not valid in this case): if you integrated first wrt $r$ you'd have seen the problem (a divergent improper integral).

Comment: @gniourf_gniourf : The lefthand side is zero because when we insert the jacobian ,the $r^2$ term gets cancelled. But, the point that the vector field is not $C^1$ seems to be the correct answer.

Comment: @SrinivasK The $r^2$ term gets cancelled doesn't mean your substitution (with the Jacobian) is valid: the substitution _is valid on domains where the Jacobian isn't nil!_ Maybe I didn't express my idea properly in my previous comment (sorry about that). My point is that the hypotheses of _all_ the theorems used _are not fulfilled here_.

Comment: Mhh, okay, that's not very nice since we only learned in our theoretical-physics-class to apply this theorem. We only did a "proof-sketch" to understand the idea behind it.